# Trying to setup nfcpy, Returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ndef'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, nfc

I am trying to setup a PN532_NFC_HAT on a Raspberry Pi with nfcpy but I am having problems with modules.

**What I have done so far:**

I have installed nfcpy on my Raspberry Pi by simply doing this in the terminal.

```
$ pip install -U nfcpy
```

And I have verified the installation with this command

```
$ python -m nfc --search-tty
```

And so far it works, nfcpy can find my NFC Reader

Then I have cloned the examples from [github](https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy)
with the command

```
pi@raspberrypi: git clone https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy.git
```

and entered the examples-folder

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/nfcpy/examples $
```

**What happens:**

nfcpy has some example programs but when I try to run them they return various errors.

If I for an example run this command on one of the examples, Tagtool.py

```
python3 tagtool.py
```

I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tagtool.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ndef
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ndef'
```

Other examples return errors about not finding the module named nfc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just do ```pip install ndef ```

Comment: It doesn't work

pi@raspberrypi:~/nfcpy/examples $ pip install ndef

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting ndef
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/02/95e0b1f12b222fb9e6c9bd7479ed5b3ea070ecaabc22fb20d457aea963d6/ndef-0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ndef) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: ndef
Successfully installed ndef-0.2

Comment: Because I still get this message: 

pi@raspberrypi:~/nfcpy/examples $ python3 tagtool.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tagtool.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ndef
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ndef'

Comment: Is this because you are installing for python2 but then executing on python 3? Try `python3 -m pip install -U nfcpy`.

Comment: Wow, it was as simple as that @PaulRooney. Thanks - I feel a bit stupid right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below ↓

```
pip uninstall nfcpy
pip3 install nfcpy
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install nfcpy
```